# Why does the python broadcaster not receive messages when configured with PostgreSQL backend?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to get broadcaster work with FastAPI and a PostgreSQL database with notifications enabled.

Here is the code I use

FastAPI (test_broadcaster.py)

```
from broadcaster import Broadcast

broadcast = Broadcast("postgres://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/<database>")

async def broadcast_ws_receiver(websocket):
    async for message in websocket.iter_text():
        await broadcast.publish(channel="account", message=message)

async def broadcast_ws_sender(websocket):
    async with broadcast.subscribe(channel="account") as subscriber:
        async for event in subscriber:
            await websocket.send_text(event.message)
```

FastAPI (router.py)

```
from fastapi.routing import APIRouter
from fastapi.websockets import WebSocket
from fastapi.concurrency import run_until_first_complete

from test_broadcaster import broadcast_ws_sender, broadcast_ws_receiver

router = APIRouter()

@router.websocket("/broadcast")
async def broadcast_ws(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    
    await run_until_first_complete(
        (broadcast_ws_receiver, {"websocket": websocket}),
        (broadcast_ws_sender, {"websocket": websocket}),
    )
```

PostgreSQL (trigger name) # on the table account

```
account
```

PostgreSQL (trigger_function)

```
BEGIN
  PERFORM pg_notify(
    'account',
    json_build_object(
      'operation', TG_OP,
      'record', row_to_json(NEW)
    )::text
  );

  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

When making the websocket connection connection and update the table to trigger a notification, nothing happends. Also not when using

```
NOTIFY account, 'hello world';
```

When changing to Redis it is working flawless, from Redis to websocket and websocket to Redis.

Is this a bug? Or I'm missing something in the code?

Comment: If `broadcast` depends on SQLAlchemy, try making the connection string like `postgresql://<username>:<password>@localhost:5432/<database>`; as of 1.4 SQLA not longer supports "postgres" as a url scheme.

Comment: @snakecharmerb; Thanks for your comment, I will check this soon and hope it will be this simple :)

Comment: @snakecharmerb; This small change helped me setting up the connection!

Only one issue left and that is that I'm not receiving messages from the NOTIFY on PostgreSQL. When send a NOTIFY, it is receiving on the PostgreSQL server, but not on the websocket.
When sending a message on the websocket, it is also received on an active LISTENER on the PostgreSQL server.